# 10 gigabit or 1 gigabit switch

Tags: switch

We are planning to move mysql to dedicated box. At this moment we have web servers and mysql is running on each. Question is: cheaper is to buy 10G switch and put 10G network card into mysql server. Or buy normal gigabit switch and connect mysql box to switch with multiple network cables. In 1G scenario then we give each web server different mysql IP address. I don't think, that mysql box with one 1G link is enough to to satisfy multiple web box mysql traffic.

At this moment we have 3 servers witch are running mysql/web. Plan is to add fourth server for mysql only. Thanks.

**Edit:**

if we buy 1G switch with mini-GBIC ports. Can we put in mini-GBIC 10G connectors and then connect mysql box to that port?

Comment: Do you really think your network is going to be a problem?  I/O is usually a bigger issue.

Comment: that is shared hosting environment.

Comment: a 1Gbps link will give you about 125MB of theoretical throughput. In reality with Ethernet and TCP overhead, you'll see closer to 90-100MB as a max for most enterprise-grade hardware. Are you *really* pushing 90-100MB per second from your database servers to your web servers? That's an *awful* lot.

Comment: You'll likely be surprised at one 1Gb is able to handle.

Comment: @Guntis re: "Can we put in mini-GBIC 10G connectors", this is specific to the type of switch you buy. consult the product documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL is inherently quite a bandwidth-light system, unless you're doing a LOT of big bulk loads or routinely need to pull down massive results you won't see much benefit from using 10Gbps NICs. There IS one area where it can be useful, if you backup over Ethernet and have sufficient data to justify the cost.

What I'd do is monitor your network traffic at 1Gbps and if you see consistent, prolonged NIC use at >95% of 1Gbps then consider the 10Gbps option, otherwise stick with 1Gbps for now.

Comment: case that 1 mysql box is for 3 different web boxes, that doesn't matter ?

Comment: It depends on the load, best just measure your traffic over time and see if you need it, if this is for client-side web traffic do you have more than 1Gbps of outgoing bandwidth anyway?

Comment: outgoing bandwidth is 100M

Comment: So there's a limit to how much you'd benefit from going over 1Gbps then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic load balancing bonding or with LACP (switch must support it). Total bandwidth can reach the sum of all physical connections (4 gb for four 1 gb links to the MySQL server), but bandwidth for single connection will be limited to single link (1 gb). I definitely recommend to use LACP to eliminate TCP re-transmissions.